# PHP Loop error - only part of the loop is looped?

Tags: php, loops

Me and several friends taking the same programming course have been confused by this for hours so far, hopefully someone here can help.
The aim is to take a list of urls, split by new lines, prepend [ img] and append [/ img] for each URL, as suitable for a bulletin board. The actual code includes a switch to allow for both [ img] and [ thumb] bbcodes, but both have the same effect.
Instead of outputting

```
[ img]1[/ img]
[ img]2[/ img]
```

it outputs

```
[ img]1
2[ /img]
```

The same happens for any number of URLs. Here's the code I am using.

```
   <?php

    $url_f = (isset($_POST['text'])) ? $_POST['text'] : false;
    $thumb = (isset($_POST['type'])) ? $_POST['type'] : false;
    $urls = ($url_f) ? explode('\n',$url_f) : '';

    ?>

    <textarea rows='20' cols='40' readonly='1'>


    <?php
    switch ($thumb){
        case 'img':
            for ($i = count($urls)-1; $i >= 0; $i--)
            {
                echo "[img]". $urls[$i] ."[/img]\n";
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;

        case 'thumb':
            for ($i = count($urls)-1; $i >= 0; $i--)
            {
                echo '[thumb]'. $urls[$i] ."[/thumb]\n";
            }
            break;

    }

    ?>

    </textarea>
```

Comment: `default` should come last you know, otherwise it will skip anything beyond it.

Comment: Doesn't appear to in this case, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: That switch is really funky. Also have personally never seen the default on anything but the last line of the switch {}. Is $urls actually being populated as expected?

Comment: Yes, I've tried echoing out $urls[0], $urls[1], etc, they all work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There are three different types of newlines: \r, \n, and \r\n. I don't do much web development, but different OSes will still probably send different newlines, so you'll have to do some checking to find out what character(s) to split with.</strike>

In your code, since \n isn't working, the newline is probably \r\n or \r.

Edit: The single quoted string literal may be the problem.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I go about checking? Could I just explode it, then check the length?

Comment: I missed something since I haven't touched PHP in a while. The single quotes you used should be replaced with double quotes in order for the escape sequences to work. Try that, and, if there's still a problem, I'll post code.

Comment: Aaaaah! Jeez, reminds me why I hate PHP so much. Spending hours pondering over the difference between single and double quotes...That fixed it. Thanks a lot to everyone who helped.

Comment: @user1013452: it's not just a PHP-ism. Many (most? all?) scripting languages that use $ for variables differentiate between `'` and `"` strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is `'\n' !== "\n"`. The former is treated as "backslash n", while the latter is processed to the line feed character (ASCII 0xA, bein LF). See [Double Quoted Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for more info.

Regarding your loop, you might want to look into [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).